# Python 3: Creating DataFrame with parsed data

Tags: pandas, python-3.4

The following data has been parsed from a stock API.  The dataframe has the headers of each column in the Dataset respectively.  Is there anyway I can link the data to the dataframe effectively creating a labeled data array/table?

## DataFrame

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Date','Close','High','Low','Open','Volume'])
```

## DataSet

20140502,36.8700,37.1200,36.2100,36.5900,22454100
20140505,36.9100,37.0500,36.3000,36.6800,13129100
20140506,36.4900,37.1700,36.4800,36.9400,19156000
20140507,34.0700,35.9900,33.6700,35.9900,66062700
20140508,33.9200,34.5700,33.6100,33.8800,30407700
20140509,33.7600,34.1000,33.4100,34.0100,20303400
20140512,34.4500,34.6000,33.8700,33.9900,22520600
20140513,34.4000,34.6900,34.1700,34.4300,12477100
20140514,34.1700,34.6500,33.9800,34.4800,17039000
20140515,33.8000,34.1900,33.4000,34.1800,18879800
20140516,33.4100,33.6600,33.1000,33.6600,18847100
20140519,33.8900,33.9900,33.2800,33.4100,14845700
20140520,33.8700,34.4700,33.6700,33.9900,18596700
20140521,34.3600,34.3900,33.8900,34.0000,13804500
20140522,34.7000,34.8600,34.2600,34.6000,17522800
20140523,35.0200,35.0800,34.5100,34.8500,16294400
20140527,35.1200,35.1300,34.7300,35.0000,13057000
20140528,34.7800,35.1700,34.4200,35.1500,16960500
20140529,34.9000,35.1000,34.6700,34.9000,9780800
20140530,34.6500,34.9300,34.1300,34.9200,13153000
20140602,34.8700,34.9500,34.2800,34.6900,9178900
20140603,34.6500,34.9700,34.5800,34.8000,6557500
20140604,34.7300,34.8300,34.2600,34.4800,9434100

Comment: How is the dataset stored - array form, pandas dataframe, list of lists or in file?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that you are receiving the data as a `list` of `list`s. So something like -

```
vals = [[20140502,36.8700,37.1200,36.2100,36.5900,22454100], [20140505,36.9100,37.0500,36.3000,36.6800,13129100], ...]
```

In that case, you can populate your `dataframe` with [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html#pandas.DataFrame.loc) -

```
for index, val in enumerate(vals):
    df.loc[index] = val
```

Which will give you -

```
In [6]: df
Out[6]: 
       Date  Close   High    Low   Open    Volume
0  20140502  36.87  37.12  36.21  36.59  22454100
1  20140505  36.91  37.05   36.3  36.68  13129100
...
```

Here, [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) gives us the index of the row, so we can use that to populate the dataframe index.

If somehow the data was saved as csv, then you can simply use `read_csv` -

```
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv', names=['Date','Close','High','Low','Open','Volume'])
```